# Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type (enum)

Tags: typescript

Have an issue.

While assigning enum value to the enum attribute, getting an error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CountryCode'.`
Which i suppose i shouldn't get cause both attribute and value are the same `enum` type

**service with `enum` attribute:**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserData {
  private _country_code: CountryCode;
  private _currency_code: CurrencyCode;

  constructor() { }


  get country_code(): CountryCode {
    return this._country_code;
  }

  set country_code(value: CountryCode) {
    this._country_code = value;
  }
  get currency_code(): CurrencyCode {
    return this._currency_code;
  }
  set currency_code(value: CurrencyCode) {
    this._currency_code = value;
  }
}
```

**enum**

```
export enum CountryCode {
  TH,
  BGD,
}
```

**usage case with an error:**

```
this.userData.country_code = CountryCode[data.country_code];
```

Answer (score 4):

enums in TypeScript are transpiled into plain objects:

```
CountryCode[CountryCode["TH"] = 0] = "TH";
CountryCode[CountryCode["BGD"] = 1] = "BGD";
```

Following of that, there is two ways you might use them:

```
name:  CountryCode.TH <-- 0    (number)
index: CountryCode[0] <-- 'TH' (string)
                               ^^^^^^^
```

The latter throws an error if you try to assign it to a variable of type *CountryCode*. So I believe this is what is happening here.
See this example on [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20UserData%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20_country_code%3A%20CountryCode%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20country_code()%3A%20CountryCode%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this._country_code%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20set%20country_code(value%3A%20CountryCode)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this._country_code%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20CountryCode%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20TH%2C%0D%0A%20%20BGD%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20UserData()%3B%0D%0Aa.country_code%20%3D%20CountryCode.TH%3B%0D%0Aa.country_code%20%3D%20CountryCode%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.country_code%20%3D%20CountryCode%5BCountryCode%5B0%5D%5D%3B).

However, given the above output, this should work:

```
this.userData.country_code = data.country_code;
OR
this.userData.country_code = CountryCode[CountryCode[data.country_code]];
```

But the latter does not make that much sense.

Answer (score 0):

`data.country_code` is probably already of type `CountryCode`, therefore `this.userData.country_code = data.country_code;` should be enough. Calling `CountryCode[...]` converts between the integer and string representation:

```
CountryCode[CountryCode["TH"] = 0] = "TH";
CountryCode[CountryCode["BGD"] = 1] = "BGD";
```

is the compiled code for `enum CountryCode {...}`.