# Typecript Enum access returns type 'string' rather than keyof typeof Enum, but expects keyof typeof Enum instead of 'string

Tags: typescript, enums

minimal example of problem:

```
enum EXAMPLE {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
}

EXAMPLE[EXAMPLE[EXAMPLE.FIRST]]; // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=6&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAogGgQQLIAUAyMoG8BQV9QBiAkgEoDKAKgDR4HkwDCA8gHIAitAvjjvMuhgBtfqgwjEYmADoSFSgF0FQA)

according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520687
 unless I'm misreading it, this should be correct?

Based on the compiled javascript, this type error makes no sense to me, and based on the what I presumed to be the internal type of the enum, this also makes no sense.

Why do enum types behave inconsistently regarding their keys?  (i.e. why do they seem to be typed as something akin to `Record<'FIRST'|'SECOND',0|1> & Record<0|1,string>` rather than `Record<'FIRST'|'SECOND',0|1> & Record<0|1,'FIRST'|'SECOND'>`)

I can construct a pseudo-enum object that behaves the way I desire but I'd rather be able to use existing language features and gain the benefits thereof (conciseness, intellisense,etc.).

Is there a good fix for this, or something I'm missing?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I think what you're asking is, "Why does the [enum reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) result in type `string` instead of type `'FIRST' | 'SECOND'`. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: The answer probably ends up being: 1. enums in TypeScript are wacky, inconsistent beasts with narrow use cases, and 2. the workaround is to use a different approach.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin essentially yes.  the more I use Typescript's enums, the more I'm realizing they're remarkably restrictive and inconsistent.  is there a good polyfill or preprocessor or something I can do to make them typed correctly?  Any custom solution I can write is more verbose than just enum { ...vals } and I'll do so if needed but I'd love to be able to keep the syntactic sugar